# Darking image lines using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, threshold

How can the gridlines in the image below be blackened using OpenCV so that they are more prominent? I tried thresholding but it washes out the gridlines.

[image]

Comment: you can use [Thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2021/05/12/adaptive-thresholding-with-opencv-cv2-adaptivethreshold/)

```py
import cv2 

image1 = cv2.imread('Naw6P.png') 
img = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                                          cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 51, 5)
cv2.imshow('Adaptive Gaussian', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: output after adaptive gaussian thresholding]